# I don't want to configure any relationship in Entity Framework, but it's asking me to configure one, I just need the code for reusability

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using Entity Framework, I don't want to configure any relationship between my entities, just want them for code reusability, but I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'StallType.CashCollateral' of type 'CashCollateral'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

My code:

```
public class Stall
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public StallDetails StallDetails { get; set; }
}

public class StallDetails
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public StallPeculiarities StallPeculiarities { get; set; }
}

public class StallPeculiarities
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public StallType StallType { get; set; }
}

public class StallType
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public double TenorInMonths { get; set; }
    public double RentalRate { get; set; }
    public SecurityDeposit SecurityDeposit { get; set; }
    public CashCollateral CashCollateral { get; set; }
}

public class SecurityDeposit
{
    public double Staff { get; set; }
    public double Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CashCollateral
{
    public double Staff { get; set; }
    public double Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So how are you going to populate the property? Should EF Core ignore it? (in which case the exception tells you exactly what you need to do) Or do you want EF Core to store something in a table? Maybe as an owned type?

Comment: You can add `[NotMapped]` attribute to the navigation properties. e.g. `[NotMapped]public CashCollateral CashCollateral { get; set; }`.